# regarding installation

Tags: installation

```
madhusudan@ubuntu:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
madhusudan@ubuntu:~$
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by not being root.

You can solve this by running `sudo apt-get update`.